# Android Upload APK Change Company Name

Tags: android

Quick question, when your app is uploaded to the Google Playstore, the normal view is Image Icon (on the left), then next to the Icon on the right you get 1) App name and below it is 2) Company name and below it is 3) Rating, I'm interested in number 2 (company name), how can I change this? It currently has my name and not the company name?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, on the Android Console under settings is Developer name, well I am my own company and my name of course should go under developer name but since this reflects under the app name I suppose I can change my name to company name instead, still would have preferred having two fields, developer name AND company name but anyway solved.